# Conflicting types error on structure array

Tags: c, arrays, structure

I have following C code:

```
#define total 5

typedef struct data{
    int id;
    int age;
    char name[50];
}groups;

groups people[total];
people[1] = {1, 20, "Joseph"};
```

However I'm getting an error saying

> 'conflicting types in 'people'

and I don't understand why.

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the full error message?

Comment: error: conflicting types for 'people' and 

warning: excess elements in array initializer [enabled by default]|

Comment: Just a quick explanation: the {} in that line is taken to mean a list of *elements* in the people[] array, not a list of fields in one element as you meant. And since 1, 20 and "Joseph" do not fit the definition of groups, the compiler complains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either one of these will work:

```
groups people[total];
people[1] = (groups) {1, 20, "Joseph"};
```

or:

```
groups people[total] = {
    [1] = {1, 20, "Joseph"}
};
```

Comment: Thanks, worked, I also noticed I was using [1],[2],[3],etc... when I needed to start at 0 (duh), and that corrected the warning, leaving only the error, which your answer did correct, thanks alot !

Comment: @DanielFernandes You can accept the answer as correct answer if it did resolve your issue ...